# elrtef issue - undefined is not a function error when trying to open image dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii, elrte

I have installed http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/elrtef/ extension and given following configuration.

```
 $this->widget('application.widgets.elrtef.elRTE', array( 
        'model' => $usemodel,
        'attribute' => 'mediabody',
    'value'=>$usemodel->mediabody,

        'options' => array(
                'doctype'=>'js:\'<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">\'',
                'cssClass' => 'el-rte',
                'cssfiles' => array('css/elrte-inner.css'),
                'absoluteURLs'=>true,
                'allowSource' => true,
                'lang' => 'en',
                'styleWithCss'=>'',
                'height' => 400,
                'fmAllow'=>true, //if you want to use Media-manager
                'fmOpen'=>'js:function(callback) {$("<div id=\"elfinder\" />").elfinder(%elfopts%);}',//here used placeholder for settings
                'toolbar' => 'basic',
        ),
        'elfoptions' => array( //elfinder options
            'url'=>'auto',  
            'passkey'=>'mypass',
            'lang'=>'en',
            'dialog'=>array('width'=>'900','modal'=>true,'title'=>'Media Manager'),
            'closeOnEditorCallback'=>true,
            'editorCallback'=>'js:callback'
        ),
        )
      );
```

I got the elrte editor.

While click the image icon in tool bar, the image dialog box opens with **Properties, Advanced, Events Links** only.

I don't get the Image url and other fields.  I got the following errors in console.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)  elfinder/js/i18n/elfinder.en.js
>
> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method
>   'toLowerCase'.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is due to conflict of another widget of yii.